# Is there a way to use declare-styleable to open the choose a resource dialog that lets you select a color or a drawable in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, declare-styleable

Having the custom view `TestView` and declaring the following custom attribute:

```
<declare-styleable name="TestView">
    <attr name="testAttr" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

upon trying to open the resource selection dialog from the attribute overview in the visual editor of Android Studio, the dialog opens and only allows for string resources to be selected. How can the above be modified to show the same dialog that appears when selecting the background resource for a view?

[The undesired dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpLyA.png)

[The desired dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clrzV.png)

Thanks in advance for your help! =)

EDIT------

I tried modifying the code to be:

```
<declare-styleable name="TestView">
    <attr name="testAttr" format="reference|color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

as this is what I found `android:background` to be, but the dialog to only select color resources opens instead.

[The new undesired dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKSuk.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new color you need to write this code at `colors.xml`, inside "values":   (replace the hex number for the color you want)

```
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
```

Then, once you create it, call it like that at `activity_main.xml`:  (in the case you want to modify a textlayout)

```
android:textColor="@color/white"
```

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! That's not quite what I'm looking for, I want to be able to reference a drawable or color from the custom attribute. For example :

`testAttr="@drawable/test"`
OR
`testAttr="@color/white"`

=)

Comment: If yo find how to do it please link it here, thanks in advance!

Comment: Will do when/if I do :)